# Indirect SCP connection

Tags: ssh, scp, nautilus

I use ssh and scp to connect to a remote server.

Due to a ip/proxy limitation on the remote server, I have to connect first to another server. For example, if I want to connect to "SERVER-A", I have to ssh to SERVER-0 and from SERVER-0 ssh to SERVER-A. Thats ok, just a simple additional step on the login.

Now im trying to connect using Nautilus. Its there any way to indicat it to connect via the intermediate server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a ssh tunnel.

For example, on your computer, enter the following command (and keep the connection open):
`ssh -L 12345:SERVER-A:22 user@SERVER-0`.

This way, you can now connect Nautilus to `localhost:12345`, and it will connect you to SERVER-A, via SERVER-0.

Depending on your configuration, you may need to authorize the forwarding to a remote host in the `sshd` configuration file on SERVER-0 (usually `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`).